# A correct way to convert byte[] in java to unsigned char* in C++, and vice versa?

Tags: android, c++, java-native-interface

I'm newbie in C++ and JNI, I try to find a correct way to convert byte[] in java to unsigned char* in C++ by using JNI, and vice versa ! (I'm working on android)
After looking for a solution in google and SO, I haven't found a good details way to convert byte[] in java to C++. Please help me, and provide a solution for a vice versa (unsigned char* in C++ to byte[] in java). Thanks very much

- **byte[] in java to unsigned char* in C++:**

**JAVA :**

```
private static native void nativeReceiveDataFromServer(byte[] value, int length);
```

**JNI:**

```
... (JNIEnv* env, jobject thiz, jbyteArray array, jint array_length)
{
    ???
}
```

PS: I modified my question for being a real question for my problem :(

Comment: Well of course it is. You can't write C++ in C. Not a real question.

Comment: @EJP I think you hasn't read all my question ! The main question is "I'm newbie in C++ and JNI, I try to find a correct way to convert byte[] in java to unsigned char* in C++ by using JNI, and vice versa !.... Please correct me if I'm wrong, and provide a solution for a vice versa (unsigned char* in C++ to byte[] in java)" ! May you help me ? I think you shouldn't downgrade my point if you hasn't read all the question!

Comment: seems to me like you're trying to use a c compiler to compile c++ code.

Comment: I searched some post in google, and see they can use the "new" in jni. However I haven't found the solution ! If you can provide me the solution to use the new or it can't use ?

Comment: @Zharf May you help me ? I don't know my solution for converting byte[] in java to C++ is good or not, and I'm searching the vice versa solution ! Please help me if you can !

Comment: The compiler message which you have just removed showed clearly that you are using C++ syntax with a C compiler. You can't do it. It doesn't make sense. All your edit accomplishes is removal of all the useful information. What's left is not a real question.

Comment: :) I think I found a solution for that, thanks for your concern.

Answer (score 82, accepted):

You can use this to convert `unsigned char` array into a `jbyteArray`

```
jbyteArray as_byte_array(unsigned char* buf, int len) {
    jbyteArray array = env->NewByteArray (len);
    env->SetByteArrayRegion (array, 0, len, reinterpret_cast<jbyte*>(buf));
    return array;
}
```

to convert the other way around...

```
unsigned char* as_unsigned_char_array(jbyteArray array) {
    int len = env->GetArrayLength (array);
    unsigned char* buf = new unsigned char[len];
    env->GetByteArrayRegion (array, 0, len, reinterpret_cast<jbyte*>(buf));
    return buf;
}
```

Comment: how about the below solution, is it different than yours ? What's better one?

`jbyte* content_array = (*env)->GetByteArrayElements(env, array, NULL);
 //if (content_array == NULL)
  //return 0;
 
 ReceiveDataFromServer(content_array, array_length);
 (*env)->ReleaseByteArrayElements(env, array, content_array, JNI_ABORT); `

Comment: That will work pretty much the same. The difference is that in your code you provide the native code a buffer to put data into, in my version the native code creates the buffer. Which is better depends on the use case.

Comment: @Zharf, how is "buf" get freed in as_unsigned_char_array()?

Comment: @ransh it isn't, it needs to be deleted manually after it's not needed anymore. Smart pointers might be preferred by some for this, of course.

Comment: I've tried to pass large byte array (about 1.5 Mb) into as_unsigned_char_array(jbyteArray), and it causes a crash with a message "Fatal signal 11 (SIGSEGV), code 2, fault addr 0x9f235000 in tid 12821 (Thread-34144)".

Comment: Will it work with const char*, instead of unsigned char*?

Comment: The best answer to converting an uchar array to byte array in stackoverflow.

Answer (score -1):

The array buf is a variable on stack. After leaving the function is this variable undefined.

A solution is separating this function in two, one to compute the size and another with a pointer to now the allocated array as parameter to fill in the values.