# Write byte[] passed through jbytearray to a file

Tags: java, android, c++, android-ndk, java-native-interface

I need to write into a file a byte array that i pass to a function in C++ using jni.

That's my Java code

```
private void writeData(byte[] array) {
    Native nativeobject = new Native();

    long tsize = this.size;
    long incremental = 0;

    while(tsize != 0 && !this.stopped) {
        nativeobject.writeFile(whereToSave, array);

        publishProgress(incremental);
        incremental += TRANCE_SIZE;
        tsize -= TRANCE_SIZE;

    }
}
```

And that's my function header

```
JNIEXPORT jbyteArray JNICALL Java_it_mls_secureeraser_algorithms_Native_writeFile(JNIEnv *jni, jobject thiz,
        jstring jfileName, jbyteArray jarray) {

    const char *fileName = jni->GetStringUTFChars(jfileName, 0);

    int len = jni->GetArrayLength (jarray);
    unsigned char* buf = new unsigned char[len];
    jni->GetByteArrayRegion (jarray, 0, len, reinterpret_cast<jbyte*>(buf));

    FILE *output = fopen(fileName, "a+");
    fwrite(buf, sizeof(unsigned char*), sizeof(buf), output);
    fclose (output);
}
```

how can I pass from jbytearray to something that I can write to my file?
Thanks for help

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Have a look here: [A correct way to convert byte[] in java to unsigned char* in C++, and vice versa?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16667029/a-correct-way-to-convert-byte-in-java-to-unsigned-char-in-c-and-vice-versa). I faced similar problem before and it was the solution.

Comment: It doesn't work pretty well.. My array size is 1KB, but when I write a tranche of it, it only writes 0,02KB

Comment: Have you checked that conversion is ok? I looked my code, and I used exactly the same code as the post above. Maybe you have some errors on writing?

Comment: Conversion works pretty well.. something is wrong with fwrite

Comment: Try something like this: fwrite(buf, sizeof(unsigned char), sizeof(buf)/sizeof(unsigned char), output);

Comment: Still not working, it wrote 4bytes (0000) per time (instead of 1048576)

_

Solved by statically writing:
fwrite(buf, 1, 1048576, output);

What about dinamically writing?

Comment: Try with: fwrite(buf, sizeof(unsigned char), len/sizeof(unsigned char), output);.

Comment: "len/sizeof(unsigned char)" it is not neccesary, with "len" should work too. Copy-pasting errors :).