# How to convert a byte array in C++ to a jbytearray

Tags: c++, java-native-interface, arrays

I am writing a function in C++ that returns a byte array to a java program using JNI.  How do I convert that byte array to a jbyteArray that I can return to Java?  I am new to C++.

EDIT: I am looking for a way to convert a **byte** array to jbyteArray, not char *

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/16667029/a-correct-way-to-convert-byte-in-java-to-unsigned-char-in-c-and-vice-versa

Comment: That question explains how to convert from char * not byte array, which is what I need.

Comment: in C++ a byte array is a char array.